# Unit test for directive with $interval.flush throw 'Possibly unhandled rejection'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have created directive that use $interval service:

```
directive('dir', ['$animate', '$interval', function($animate, $interval) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        model:'='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.elements = [];

        this.register = function(element) {
          $scope.elements.push(element);
        }

        $scope.animate = function() {
          //do some animation
        }
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.animation = $interval(function() {
          scope.animate();
        }, 500);

        scope.$watch('model', function(value) {
          if(value == false) {
            if(scope.animation) {
              $interval.cancel(scope.animation);
              scope.animation = undefined;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

When I write a unit test for animate method I receive:
Possibly unhandled rejection: {} thrown

```
 beforeEach(inject(['$compile', '$rootScope', '$interval',
  function($compile, $rootScope, $interval) {
    var element = angular.element('<dir model="true"></dir>');
    var directive = $compile(element)($rootScope.$new());
    controller = directive.controller('loading');
    scope = directive.isolateScope();   
    interval = $interval;

    scope.$digest();
  }]));

  fit('trigger animation', function() {
    interval.flush(500);
  });
```

As I can understand this is because of not resolved Promise that was returned by $interval inside my link function. But can't figure out how to do it properly.

```
"angular": "~1.6.0",
"angular-mocks": "~1.6.0",
```

Comment: Couldn't replicate. AngularJS version?

Comment: Can you try to replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/Hnj74uguFcX78Xc19cYl?p=preview

Comment: Thank you) You make me think what else could be wrong - it is ui-router... it was the reason, not sure why, cause if I don't use flush, everything is fine...

Comment: It is $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main'); inside config, cause this issue..

Comment: Did you solve it or still need help?